# Get segments visitor belongs to via Adobe Analytics JavaScript API

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm looking to determine whether it's possible via Adobe's s_code.js  or possibly visitorAPI.js to be able to find out which segments the current visitor belongs to.

For example, I might have a segment which is for any users which have spent more than a particular amount in the past. I'm looking to be able to identify that the visitor on my page at the current time is one of those users.

Thanks.

- https://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2014/06/17/the-visitor-id-service/
- https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visid_overview.html